# Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name "feature name" AND Unrecognized feature

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a google sheets with an HTMl and javascript. When I click in the button that triggers a code (insert data in the gsheets), the html form turns blank and console returns many errors:

```
Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “speaker”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “usb”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “vibrate”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “vr”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “accelerometer”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “ambient-light-sensor”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “autoplay”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “encrypted-media”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “gyroscope”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “magnetometer”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “midi”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “payment”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “picture-in-picture”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “speaker”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “usb”. userCodeAppPanel

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “vibrate”. userCodeAppPanel
```

Sometimes the erros are:

```
Unrecognized feature: 'speaker'

Unrecognized feature: 'vr' 
(...)
```

[Console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhtam.png)

I have no idea where to start to look on how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I’m still getting all this messages but I actually figure out what was happening with the blank screen. The button I was using to add data was “submitting the form”. ‍♂️
I think I could ignore these errors since I’m not using any of these features